# Are elements in $V \otimes K[G]$ just functions from $G$ to $V$ of the form $g \mapsto \sum_i f_i(g)v_i$ for $f_i \in K[G]$ and $v_i \in V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $K$ denote an algebraically closed field, $G$ be an affine algebraic group, $V$ a $K$-vector space.

If I am given two function $f,f' \in K[G]$ then I know that I can view elements in $K[G]$ as functions from $G$ to $K$ so the following holds:
$$ f = f' \iff f(g) = f'(g) \quad \forall g \in G.$$
Inspired by this property I wonder if a similar result holds for $V \otimes K[G]$.

Let $h ,h' \in V \otimes K[G]$. Can one view elements in $V \otimes K[G]$ as functions from $G \to V \otimes K \cong K$ and use the following property.

$$ \sum_{i}v_i\otimes f_i = \sum_j v_i'\otimes f_i' \iff \sum_if_i(g)v_i = \sum_jf_j(g)v_j \quad \forall g \in G.$$

Could someone double check the following proof ?

For any $f \in K[G]$ and $v \in V$ define
$$ fv : G \rightarrow V: g \mapsto f(g)v.$$
Then let $W := \text{Span} \{fv : f \in K[G],v \in V\}$ and I claim that we have a vector space isomorphism

$$ V \otimes K[G] \cong W$$
given by $\Phi : v \otimes f \mapsto fv.$ Clearly $\Phi$ is surjective. To show that it is injective let $\omega \in V \otimes K[G]$ be such that
$$ \Phi(\omega) = 0$$
Suppose $\omega = \sum_i v_i \otimes f_i$ where WLOG the $v_i$ are linearly independent then
$$ \Phi(\sum_i f_i) = 0 \iff \sum_i f_i(g)v_i = 0 \quad \forall g \in G.$$
It follows that $f_i(g) = 0$ for all $g \in G$ so $f_i = 0$ for all $i$ and $\omega =0$ proving that $\Phi$ is an isomorphism.

Hence it follows that
$$ \sum_{i}v_i\otimes f_i = \sum_j v_i'\otimes f_i' \iff \sum_if_iv_i = \sum_jf_jv_j$$
which is exactly the equivalence we wanted to prove.

Comment: Looks correct to me. You didn't use that k is algebraically closed and that G is an algebraic group though, so anmore general statement is true.